# Can you bypass a proxy server with a LiveCD/USB or Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking

It is possible? Let's say I have a Linux live CD or USB and I manage to boot from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very unlikely. As its name implies a *proxy server* acts as an **intermediary** between you and the router that connects to the outside world.

When you boot any OS (installed on *hard drive* or from a *live CD or USB*), the OS needs a *network configuration* that can be *created manually* or *obtained automatically* from a DHCP server.

On any case, the network configuration needs to know the *"way out"* of the local network.

If systems admin have done a good job, then the **only way out** will be the *proxy server*, so if you try to ignore the proxy server, your traffic won't get out of the local network.

Comment: It might be better to answer 'Yes, as long as there is an alternate way round' or 'Unlikely as most proxy servers are setup...'.  Saying No, when it is possible seems too restrictive.  We don't know what purpose the proxy server is playing.

Comment: On the other hand, @fswings, somehow the question seems to suggest that there is no way around the proxy server when using Windows. Given that, using another OS does not suddenly introduce ways to circumvent such restrictions, I'd assume. :-)

Comment: @fswings Changed from "No" to "very unlikely".

Comment: Good point, perhaps what needs emphasising is that bypassing a proxy server cannot be done by changing OS but by using an alternate way out. If one doesn't exist then you can't.

Comment: It could also be that existing browser doesn't allow user to change proxy settings which,  a boot disk os would.

Comment: @Arjan I assume that he hasn't Administrative rights on the installed Windows 7, so he can't fiddle with network settings.